# HighCharts Pie chart is not showing all of dataLabels, it's cut off

Tags: html, highcharts

I am creating a Pie chart in which I have to show any amount of data. Now the problem is, it is not showing all of the dataLabels. Here is what I am getting :
[image]

Please have a look into jsfiddle example: [`example`](https://jsfiddle.net/pooja_k/dpLcr6hz/5/)

A possible solution would be to decrease the line spacing/ distance between the labels. Or any other solution ?

Comment: share a jsfiddle with the example and chances of someone providing a [working] solution will be higher

Comment: There is no label cause there is not enough place for them. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aksw4q32/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have added jsfiddle example link. Please have a look and let me know better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Data labels are not rendered because there is not enough space for them. However, you can decrease the font size, and set `padding = 0` to make more space for them.

**Code:**

```
dataLabels: {
  padding: 0,
  style: {
    fontSize: '8px'
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yjkpo38q/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#style
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#padding

Comment: Thanks @wojciech-chmiel, But still it's not showing all data labels. I have added jsfiddle example. can you please look it?

Comment: All data labels are not rendered because there is not enough space for them. Also, the chart will be unreadable and messy. The tooltip shows more info about each point.

Comment: Tool-tip is there in my code but I want print of this chart. That's why I need every data label.

Comment: I see, so perhaps it will be a better idea to group small points and show them in drilldown? Now, the chart is unreadable. You can print two charts with bigger and smaller data so that it will be neater and users can read it.

Comment: sorry, but I can not print two chart and also I can not group small points and show them in drilldown